# Rust: Is an Enum a subset of Structs?

Tags: struct, rust, enums

I've just learned that an Enum can be initialized with a custom data type.

Wouldn't that make Enums a subset of Structs? An Enum could be a Struct with a single unnamed variable which is initialized once and cannot be changed (like final variables in Java). Also, no methods can be implemented to enums.

Like this:

```rust
enum E {
  ONE(String)
}

struct S {
  one: String
}
```

Thus, in memory, both a single variable struct and enum would look the same.

Is this true or am I missing something?

Comment: By "initialized with custom data type", do you mean enum variants can carry additional payload, i.e. enums are sum types? And what do you mean by "An Enum could be a Struct with a single unnamed variable which is initialized once and cannot be changed"? Lastly, enums can have methods.

Comment: 1) custom data type like enum E { ONE(String) }. 
2) like struct E { one: String }. wouldn't that be the same?
3) didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: And what about 2, "An Enum could be a Struct with a single unnamed variable which is initialized once and cannot be changed"?

Comment: yeah I pressed enter too early. Updated it

Comment: But what with e.g. `enum E { One(String), Second(i32) }`?

Comment: OK I guess I got it. With `struct S { one: String, second: i32 }` it would take memory for both elements while `let e = E::Second(2)` would take only 4 Byte

Comment: It's more than that: in the struct version, you cannot tell what is the active variant. You have to use a discriminant. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually the opposite: structs are subsets of enums. Any struct can be represented as one-variant enum:

```rust
struct Record { ... }
struct TupleLike(...);

enum Record { Variant { ... } }
enum TupleLike { Variant(...) }
```

This enum will even have the same in-memory representation! (though it isn't guaranteed).

On the other hand, enums with multiple variants cannot be described precisely as structs. They are usually implemented as tagged unions, for example:

```rust
enum E {
    S(String),
    I(i32),
}
E::I(123);

type E_Discriminant = u8;
const E_S: E_Discriminant = 0;
const E_I: E_Discriminant = 1;
union E_Payload {
    s: String,
    i: i32,
}
struct E {
    discriminant: E_Discriminant,
    payload: E_Payload,
}
E { discriminant: E_I, payload: E_Payload { i: 123 } };
```

But even doing that manually will not provide you the whole language experience of using enums: you will unable to use pattern matching, accessing variants will be `unsafe` (and dangerous), etc..

However, when only one variant is needed, structs are more comfortable to use, and that's why they're there.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. That discriminant part is actually interesting. I was assuming the new type `String` would replace it. Doesn't make sense when I see it now.

Comment: It seems that we have pattern matching when using `union`, here is the doc [link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.union.html#matching-on-unions). Am I missing something?

Comment: @SteveLau It doesn't match the active field but any field (and thus requires `unsafe`). You can simulate pattern matching like `unsafe { match e { E { discriminant: E_I, payload: E_Payload { i } } => {}, E { discriminant: E_S, payload: E_Payload { s } } => {}, _ => {} } }`, but it requires `unsafe`, unergonomic, does not guarantee exhaustiveness and error-prone.